# Custom Error Bars in VBA for Excel Automation

Tags: excel, vba, graph, errorbar

I cannot find the mistake. I know that there are already similar questions. Unfortunately, it seems that I did not understand the syntax of Error Bars correctly.

'''

```
Dim mychart As Chart
Set mychart = oWSD.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

mychart.SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBars Direction:=xlY, Include:=xlMinusValues, 
Type:=xlCustom, Amount:="=Data and Graph!$B$12:$F$12", MinusValues:="=Data and 
Graph!$B$12:$F$12"
```

'''
I somehow get the error: Run-Time Error '448', Named argument not found.

Has someone an idea what is wrong? Thank you all <3

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use

```
mychart.SeriesCollection(1).HasErrorBars = True
```

before trying to set any error bar properties.

And use `ErrorBar` not `ErrorBars` in your posted code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.series.errorbar

`ErrorBars` doesn't take any arguments.

```vb
Dim mychart As Chart
Set mychart = oWSD.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

mychart.SeriesCollection(1).ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, _
                    Include:=xlMinusValues, _
                    Type:=xlCustom, _
                    Amount:="=Data and Graph!$B$12:$F$12", _
                    MinusValues:="=Data and Graph!$B$12:$F$12"
```